# First Chern Class of Contact Structure which is not Torsion

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, spin-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $(M,\xi)$ be a closed connected $3-$dimensional contact manifold with contact structure $\xi$. It is known that the first Chern class $c_{1}(\xi)$ defines an element in $H^{2}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ and is even.

Question: Do there exists examples of contact manifolds $(M,\xi)$ where $c_{1}(\xi)$ is **not** torsion?

Comment: You might want the Lutz–Martinet theorem on the existence of contact structures in every homotopy class of cooriented plane field on closed oriented 3–manifolds.

Comment: Could you give a reference for "It is known ..."?

Comment: Yes, $S^1\times S^2$ has an overtwisted contact structure with Chern class $\pm2$ (after orienting). It is the one which appears in near-symplectic geometry, as the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of the circles of degeneracy (of the near-symplectic 2-form). I think it is $(1-3\cos^2\theta)dt + \sqrt6\cos\theta\sin^2\theta d\phi$, but might be off a bit.

Comment: I do not know what is $c_1(\xi)$ for a contact structure $\xi$.. Wikipedia says that (or at least I understood it as) contact structure is a sub bundle of tangent bundle $TM\rightarrow M$.. So, it is a vector bundle over $M$ and we can talk about chern class.. Is this correct? Is it a complex vector bundle? (I only know to define chern class for complex vector bundles)... What does it mean to say "[---]and is even" in your first paragraph?

Comment: @abx It's a small exercise in algebraic topology: $c_1\equiv w_2$ mod 2, while $w_2(TM)=w_1(TM)=0$ always for oriented 3-manifolds, and $w_2(TM)=w_2(\xi)$. (And Koushik, yes.)

Comment: @ChrisGerig what does it mean to say it is even?. Does that means image of $c_1(\xi)$ under the obvious  map $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is zero??